# Pre-filter incompatible items in a file picker

Tags: filter, dialog

I'm implementing a file picker to let users pick a simple textual file.
The prerequisite is the file must be writable.

[image]

However, a user might input the file's path by hand too.

[image]

Should I filter out the non-writable files in the dialog already?
The downside is that would result in a duplicated validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better to show the files as disabled than to filter them out altogether; if they don't show at all, the user might wonder if it's an OS issue vs. something your system is doing deliberately. Disabled files communicate, "Our system can't use this file."

Comment: Do you think disabling the OK button is sufficient? Or should I gray them out?

Comment: You could disable the OK button until a file is selected. But ideally the files themselves should be disabled before the user can select them.

Comment: So with that you mean the user can't even click over the disabled file?

Comment: When it becomes writable, it should show as enabled again.